# how load unsplash images in gatsby using gatsby-source-unsplash

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

im trying to load images from unsplash using gatsby-source-unsplash and gatsby-plugin-remote-images
my config:

gatsby.config.js:

```
  {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-unsplash`,
      options: {
        appId: `${process.env.GATSBY_API_KEY}`,
        collections: [
          `70643713`
        ],
        // optional: will only get page 1, so increase this count to include > 10 photos
        perPage: `10`
      },
    }
```

I got the data but when trying to load the image url with GatsbyImage i got "undefine"

```
var nodx = data.allUnsplashPhoto.edges;

     return (
        <div>
            {
                nodx.map(item =>{
                    var current = item.node.urls.small;
                    console.log(current);
                    return <GatsbyImage key={item.node.id} image={current} />
                })
            }
        </div>
```

Comment: Is the collection public? Is the environment `API_KEY` properly fetched?

Comment: yes i got the data but when trying to load the path url with Gatsby Image, i got an error, that the image is "undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood your goal. Now with the new provided data:

[`gatsby-source-unsplash`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-unsplash/) only gets the data of the Unsplash images collection, but doesn't process it (not even downloads it) so you must refer to it using the `img` tag, not `GatsbyImage` (from `v3`) or `Img` (from `v2`) components. This is because Gatsby needs to parse, transform and process all images to create GraphQL nodes that will be used by `GatsbyImage` component. With the URL and a few more data, you can't use it directly, you only can refer to it with the standard `img` tag.

Regarding the [`gatsby-plugin-remote-images`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-remote-images/), needs to be used like:

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-remote-images`,
      options: {
        nodeType: 'UnsplashPhoto',
        imagePath: 'nodes[].urls',
        name:'allItemImage',
      },
```

*Note: you had a typo in the `nodeType`*

This is because, if the collection is public and the environment variable is retrieving a valid value, GraphQL will intercept and create nodes, specifically `allUnsplashPhoto` node. Allowing you to:

```
allUnsplashPhoto {
  edges {
    node {
      id
      user {
        id
        name
      }
      urls {
        full
        regular
        small
      }
      description
      created_at
    }
  }
}
```

That nodes, will be passed to the `gatsby-plugin-remote-images` using the array notation, creating valid GraphQL nodes to be used with `GatsbyImage` or `Img` component:

```
allMyNodes {
  nodes {
    localImage {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 250) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'm not sure if you must create some type of asynchronously to avoid passing `null` data to the `gatsby-plugin-remote-images` plugin. If that's the case, you may need to create an asynchronous request based on [Unsplash API endpoints](https://unsplash.com/documentation#search-photos) to get the photos array and send it to the `imagePath` node.

Comment: Thanks for response, yes im getting back de data from Unsplash but when trying to load a image with Gatsby Image. but i got an error that it is "undefined"

Comment: in my case i use this config..... 
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-remote-images`,
      options: {
        nodeType: 'UnplashPhoto',
        imagePath: 'edges[].node.urls.small',
        name:'allItemImage',
      },
but still not see the new node allItemImage that the plugin has to generate...i been trying different possibilities in the imagePath but not luck

Comment: As I said, you have a typo in the `nodeType`, you are missing an "S" in `UnSplash` type

Comment: Yes i note it, thanks! but now i get allItemImage array empty, i misunderstand how imagePath shoulds to be im sure thats the problem.

Comment: The reason why is empty is because they are not async and nested process. You may want to create an async function based on https://unsplash.com/documentation#search-photos and pass the data to the nodes